# Put resizable background image in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I had a background image on my app developed for the iphone 4 screen size, however now with the larger iphone 5 screen size the image is too small and I ideally want it to resize automatically for the iphone 5 screen size. The image is displayed via an imageView object which I hoped would mean it would automatically resize for the new screen size. Is there a way to do this please?
Thank you

Comment: Did you check the UIImageView reference or even easier, Apple's document on [Image Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIImageView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIImageView)?

Comment: conform view objects with `AutoLayout` or `AutoSizing` feature

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

- Use Autolayout constraints to ensure that the UIImageView itself
  fills the screen.
- Set the resize mask on the UIImage for the
  UIImageView to stretch the image as you'd like to fill the
  UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"]];
```

And then you don't need to use UIImageView to create a background. If you wanna use UIImageView anyway, you can use Autolayout:

1. Go to Storyboard and select the UIImageView
2. Click on "Pin" button and add the 4 Constrains (left, top, right and bottom).